# Instagram API: OAuthPermissionsException in Sandbox mode

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to post a comment on an Instagram post using the API in sandbox mode but I'm getting the following error:

```
"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "error_message": "This client has not been approved to access this resource."
```

I'm using the admin user in sandbox mode, the post I'm commenting on belongs to the same admin user.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' . $post_id . '/comments';
$data = array('access_token' => $instagram_access_token, 'text' => $comment_text);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to authenticate with `comments` scope permission and then do the comments post API call:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/

Comment: If I authenticate though then my app won't have full visibility of posts not from sandbox users, will it? so it's either enjoy full Instagram API visibility without commenting, or get comments but hugely reduce what else you can see.

Comment: "enjoy full Instagram API visibility without commenting" - how are u getting that? in sandbox its always limited. `comments` scope will get u to test posting comment in sandbox mode

Comment: Before I did any kind of authentication, I was able to search by tags or by profile, and get the full set of posts returned, not just 20. As soon as I authenticated, I could only see posts from my sandbox users. I don't know how but that's what happened.

Comment: u cannot access instagram api without authentication. did u write the code or got it from somewhere, may be it has a access_token by default?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I had authenticated already a long time ago, but I can't remember where or how. All I know is it was showing me live info from any user without limits. Then when I authenticated the new way, requesting all scopes, then I was limited to info from only my sandbox users. Maybe it was a bug with my previous access token.